# Can an interface in PHP enforce extension of a class?

Tags: php, oop

In PHP can I declare than an interface must extend a class? If not, what design pattern best fits this scenario?

I'm trying to avoid using introspection after receiving the arguments.

An example scenario: I want to create a type of command, but I don't care about the implementation.

Can I do something like the following:

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;

interface Installer extends Command
{
}

class MyCommand extends Command implements Installer
{
}

class CommandConsumer
{
    public function runCommand(Installer $installer)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Instead of:

```
abstract class Installer extends Command
{
}
```

Or:

```
class CommandConsumer
{
    public function runCommand(Command $command)
    {
        if (!$command instanceof Installer)
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Installer needed.');
    }
}
```

The the test script below yields the following fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Calculation cannot implement ConcreteClass - it is not an interface in /Users/sbuzonas/projects/sandbox/inheritenceTest.php on line 13

Call Stack:
    0.0003     238920   1. {main}() /Users/sbuzonas/projects/sandbox/inheritenceTest.php:0
```

Which leads me to believe it cannot be done.

```
<?php

class ConcreteClass
{

    public function add($a, $b)
    {
        return $a + $b;
    }
}

interface Calculation extends ConcreteClass
{

    public function calculate(array $operations);
}

class Calculator extends ConcreteClass implements Calculation
{

    public function calculate(array $operations)
    {
        list($a, $b) = $operations;
        echo $this->add($a, $b);
    }
}

$calc = new Calculator();
$calc->calculate(array(1, 2));
```

Comment: Why the downvote?  I can't find a similar question.

Comment: Well, it appears to work - - - however inexplicably, I did not get any errors when I tried doing this.

Comment: @rm-vanda Interesting, I suppose I could have tried it. I was curious if it was intended behavior in the implementation of PHP. The `extends` grammar allowing interfaces to extend classes could cause confusion if you list multiple classes.

Comment: I dont get the question. Interfaces are pure abstract classes, which means no implementation whatsoever. Don't expect them to extend anything but other interfaces (you can do multiple).

Comment: @nik I don't care about the implementation, that's why I'm creating an interface. I do however need to assert that it is of two different types, unfortunately the `Symfony Console Component` does not have an interface for a `Command` which I could easily extend with my interface.  My method can only type hint a single type afaik.

Comment: If I extend the class it makes the situation even more limiting by forcing my class hierarchy on anyone that wishes to provide their alternative implementation and eliminates any other class hierarchy as a simple solution other than an implementation by composition.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an interface with methods that make sense for your use case for example:

```
interface Installer {

    public function operation1();

    public function operation2();
}
```

Have a concrete implementation using some library class to do the work for you:

```
class MyInstaller implements Installer {

    /**
     * @var \Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command
     */
    private $command;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->command = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command();
    }

    public function operation1() {
        $this->command->analogousOperation();
    }

    public function operation2() {
        $this->command->analogousOperation();
    }

}
```

Now you can use MyInstaller wherever you need Installer and it will do the work using \Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command

This client will have no problems using it:

```
class CommandConsumer
{
    public function runCommand(Installer $installer)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: IMO, an implementation utilizing composition would be cleaner to have a `getCommand` method rather than duplicate the public api in an interface. Also, the problem that arises from that solution would be I need to implement additional handling for circumstances where the installer needs to be passed as a command to third party libraries that have no knowledge of my installer interface.

Comment: Don't think you can avoid doing work of adapting your code when you introduce some new third party library. As for getCommand method I think it defeats the whole purpose of composition. What's the point of MyInstaller then, just to hold a concrete Commnad? And on top of that it would break MyInstaller's encapsulation by exposing the fact it uses Command (a concrete class).

Comment: The implementation details of installer and command are only related in the fact that every installer should be a command. It's irrelevant even as to what version of the command implementation is being used. I have a number of installation managers that take a chain of installers and pass it to the application which expects a command. If my interface had all of the public methods of command I couldn't allow for different combinations of symfony versions utilizing my library. The goal is to allow for another 3rd party to give me an installer to satisfy what I need to do with it, and hand it off